# CSS transition during switching view

Tags: jquery, css, grid, css-transitions

I prepare some code on http://jsfiddle.net/mH5JS/4/ for switching view between list and grid.

```
$('button.lists-list').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('.lists button').on('click',function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('lists-grid')) {
        // Change view
        $('body .view-list').removeClass('view-list').addClass('view-grid');
        // Disable buttons
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('button.lists-list').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else if($(this).hasClass('lists-list')) {
        // Change view
        $('body .view-grid').removeClass('view-grid').addClass('view-list');
        // Disable buttons
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('button.lists-grid').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

How to add animation (like transition) for changing view?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do it is to explicitly change the height and width in an animation call, and not switch classes.

like so

http://jsfiddle.net/mH5JS/5/

```
$('.lists button').on('click',function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('lists-grid')) {
        // Change view
        //$('body .view-list').removeClass('view-list').addClass('view-grid');
         $('body .view-list li img').animate({            
            width: 125,
            height: 200
          });
        // Disable buttons
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('button.lists-list').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else if($(this).hasClass('lists-list')) {
        // Change view
        //$('body .view-grid').removeClass('view-grid').addClass('view-list');
        $('body .view-list li img').animate({            
            width: 55,
            height: 100
          });
        // Disable buttons
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('button.lists-grid').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
```